# execute package.json script

Tags: npm, sass

`package.json`:

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js",
    "watch-sass": "sass --watch scss/styles.scss css/styles.css",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

There is no problem when I execute `npm-start` but not `npm watch-sass`. I don't know what is wrong but the command is not recognized, I type `sass --watch scss/styles.scss css/styles.css` directly on the console and it works.

Comment: Does `npm run watch-sass` work?

Comment: Yes works,  then I don'y know why `npm start` works  without  run

Comment: Refer to my answer for more details :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```sh
npm run watch-sass
```

The reason `npm start` works is because
`npm test`, `npm start`, `npm restart`, and `npm stop` are all aliases for `npm run xxx`. Because `watch-sass` does not fall in the defaults, it requires an explicit `run` in the statement

For more details visit: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script